# How to explictly set the horizontal scale of HeatMap in Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a dataset having runs scored in a cricket match of 20 overs. On plotting this in heatmap (using plotly and dash), for few cases , the horizontal scale of heat map is going beyond 20 overs although data is present for 20 overs only.

My requirement is - I dont want the scale to go beyond 20.

In the example image as shared[image], the data set for a specific case has data from overs 14 to 20 but in heatmap, 22 is showing up. (This is happening for few cases only, the horizontal scale is automatically changing.)

Also, it will be very helpful if I can show the divisions for every cell.

The code I have written so far is as follows -

```
import plotly.express as px

kptable1 = kdf.pivot_table(index='bowling_team', columns='over', values='total_runs', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0) #kdf is the pandas dataframe
line_fig = px.imshow(kptable1,text_auto=True)
return line_fig
```

**Edit-**
The sample data is provided below -

```
       over batsman total_runs bowling_team
2097    14  p1  0               someteamx
2098    14  p1  1               someteamx
2100    14  p1  4               someteamx
2101    14  p1  0               someteamx
2108    15  p1  0               someteamx
2110    16  p1  0               someteamx
2111    16  p1  0               someteamx
145862  20  p1  0               someteamy
```

(There is no over 22 but in heatmap scale is showing 22)

Comment: I have not verified this because there was no data in the question, but there is the ability to [manually set the axis range](https://plotly.com/python/axes/#setting-the-range-of-axes-manually).  `fig.update_xaxes(range=[14, 20])`

Comment: Is it possible to set the upper limit only? Because for some players data is present from over 1, so in that case starting from 14 is an issue.

Comment: I think this feature needs a lower limit upper limit.

Comment: You could do `fig.update_xaxes(range=[kdf['over'].min(), kdf['over'].max()])`.